# JUnit assertion to force a line to be executed

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is there any junit assertion, with which i can force a line to be executed?

For example:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
        Map<String, String> fieldMapActual = (Map<String, String>) arguments[0];
        assertEquals(fieldMap, fieldMapActual);

        **assertFailIfThisLineIsNotExecuted();**

        return null;
    }
}).when(x).myMethod(xxx);
```

As i simulate the behaviour of myMethod, the method answer from the anonymous inner type will be executed at runtime of the myMethod (not at runtime of junit test), if myMethod will be called with the intended value/parameter.
In order to assert that the method is called, i must additionally define a verify (otherwise my test would still run even if the method is not called).

```
verify(x).myMethod(xxx);
```

If i had a chance to write sth like *assertFailIfThisLineIsNotExecuted* in the answer method, i would not have to define an extra verify. So again, Is there any junit assertion, with which i can force a line to be executed? Opposite of fail() so to speak, without immediately defining the method as "successful".

Comment: If you verify the processing result of `answer` you would know it. Why you cannot test the behavior of it?

Comment: myMethod is void, where doAnswer is mostly used..

Comment: You are not supposed to mock the unit that you are testing. If you are testing whether myMethod is called under a particular situation (which is what you say with "assertIfThisLineIsNotExecuted" then you really are testing your mock's behaviour

Comment: in other words, at least IMO, you should never have an `assert*` inside a `doAnswer`

Comment: There are cases, where it makes %100 sense. And it should be done that way. Ex: https://akcasoy.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/the-power-of-thenanswer/   Use Case 2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that a certain line of your test is being executed, use a boolean flag:

```
 final boolean[] wasExecuted = { false };

 ...
     wasExecuted[0] = true;
 ...

 assertTrue("Some code wasn't executed", wasExecuted);
```

But my gut feeling is that you're trying to solve a different problem.

The `verify` says "This method must have been called". It doesn't matter if you mocked an answer or not. So this is the approach that you should use.

I'm using my flag approach only when I can't create a mock for some reason. If that happens, I extend the class under test in my test code and add the flag.

The advantage of the flag over `verify` is that the flag documents in which place I expect the code to be (you can have the IDE search all places where the flag is used). `verify()` is not that easy to locate when it fails.

`verify(x).myMethod(xxx);` should be what you want. It also expresses intent.

`assertFailIfThisLineIsNotExecuted()` would also be a single line of code (so how would it be "better" than `verify`?), it's not supported by JUnit,  you would have to write code to get a good error message, etc.

Comment: I would vote +1 for `But my gut feeling is that you're trying to solve a different problem.`

Comment: Using a flag is nice, but you are right.. verify should be the right way. I was just uncomfortable when i both want to mock and verify, since the method parameters must be defined twice. I would simply prefer adding an additional parameter while defining my mock, whether this call is optional or mandatory; so i do not have to write a verify. We unfortunately have methods with 4-5 parameters, and when we even have to use ArgumentCaptor etc. you may guess that just the verify itself may consist of 3 lines or sth..

Comment: Move the `ArgumentCaptor` into helper methods so you can write `(foo(...), bar(...), baz(...))`